# Ridding Android phone of Snapfish

Tags: bloatware

Something 'gifted' my Samsung Galaxy 2 with a sharing action of Snapfish.  Because it is adjacent to my Brother print button, I found it by accident.  Other than being there and telling me it actually sent a picture to some unwanted destination, I can find no program or file named Snapfish.  Where is it hidden?  I definitely want to be rid of it.

Comment: Probably came bundled with the Brother software.

Comment: [Snapfish](http://www.snapfish.com) is a photosharing and printing app by HP. They also seem to have an [Android client](https://play.google.com/store/apps/details?id=com.snapfish.mobile&hl=en)

Comment: If you can't get rid of the app you can always [edit the share menu](http://android.stackexchange.com/questions/8112/is-there-a-way-to-edit-the-share-menu) to remove the option.

Comment: I had assumed that the client could be identified and removed. But I can work with just removing it from the share list, so thanks for the link to the discussion that names an app to do that!